# node-apn Error 513 when attempting to send Push Notification

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I have a PHP script that works great and sends messages to my iPhone over APNS but when I try to use the node-apn module, I get Error 513.

In my PHP code I do things a little differently (see below); namely, I remove the spaces from the device token and "hex" it.  I also use a combined cert-key.pem that Apple recommends creating using openssl cli.  In node-apn, it appears you have to define the cert and the key separately so I just use the respective cert/key pem files I create from openssl.  Any ideas why this might not be working?  Node code at the bottom.

PHP code:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'mytokengoeshere';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'secret';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'You have new SRC requests to approve';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' => 1
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Node.js code:

```
  var message = new apn.notification();

    message.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
    message.badge = count;
    message.sound = "ping.aiff";
    message.setAlertText("You have new " + system + " requests to Approve");
    message.payload = {'messageFrom': uid};

    var options = { "gateway": "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", "cert": __dirname + "/../resource/cert.pem", "key:": __dirname + "/../resource/key.pem", "passphrase:": "secret" };
    var service = new apn.connection(options);

    service.on('connected', function() {
        console.log("Connected");
    });

    service.on('transmitted', function(notification, device) {
        console.log("Notification transmitted to:" + device.token.toString('hex'));
    });

    service.on('transmissionError', function(errCode, notification, device) {
        console.error("Notification caused error: " + errCode + " for device ", device, notification);
    });

    service.on('timeout', function () {
        console.log("Connection Timeout");
    });

    service.on('disconnected', function() {
        console.log("Disconnected from APNS");
    });

    service.on('socketError', console.error);

    var deviceId = "fe71811122723919abc56e7f8a8d8d8s8888c8s8a8s8s881155csafe";
    var device = new apn.Device(deviceId); 
    service.pushNotification(message, device);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably help if I didn't put colons in the key for key and passphrase. Long nights will do that to you. :/